# register func for jquery.validate on validate event

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I need to bind the event when the jquery.validate validation occurs, anybody knows how to do this

Comment: it is my problem too. are you find solution for it?

Comment: only jquery.livequery plugin might help

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use `submitHandler` (for callback when the form is valid) or `invalidHandler` (for callback when it isn't); more in [the docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions).

Comment: there is a Validate() method that does the validation, doesn't it triggers any events?